# Log4j2: Understand properties based on xml-explanations

Tags: java, mongodb, logging, log4j2, slf4j

I'm new to the `Log4j2` framework and I'm using it with `SLF4j`. 
Now i wanted to log a message and put it onto a MongoDB, so took a look into the manual, where the configuration is explained with xml-configuration.

**Now here's my question: What's the best practice to find out, which properties in a .properties file have to be maintained, based on a xml-configuration?**

Let me show you the basic xml-configuration of a MongoDB Appender, based on the Log4j2 manual.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="error">
  <Appenders>
    <NoSql name="databaseAppender">
      <MongoDb3 databaseName="applicationDb" collectionName="applicationLog" server="mongo.example.org"
               username="loggingUser" password="abc123" />
    </NoSql>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="warn">
      <AppenderRef ref="databaseAppender"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I start with a local db, without any login credentials, so that's what i thought i have to fill into the `.properties` file.

```
appender.MongoDbAppender.type = MongoDb3
appender.MongoDbAppender.name = MongoDbAppender
appender.MongoDbAppender.NoSqlProvider = org.apache.logging.log4j.mongodb3.MongoDbProvider 
appender.MongoDbAppender.collectionName = LogTestCollection
appender.MongoDbAppender.databaseName = LogTestField1
```

And if i start my application with this property entries, i get the following error message:

> 2018-10-15 10:08:45,009 main ERROR MongoDb3 contains invalid
>   attributes "name", "NoSqlProvider"

I really would appreciate it, if anyone could help me please and i hope, that i gave enough information for the start of a problem examination.

Kind regards,
Julius Nickel